# How to make text appear when having a specific hashtag in URL?

Tags: javascript, html, hashtag, appearance

Is it possible to make text appear when only the right id is used? So that some text is only visible when the URL says *http://example.com#hello* and not visible when it just says *http://example.com*

*(I'm not from an English-speaking-country so I'm having a hard time describing this.)*

Comment: `window.location.hash`.  If you have difficulty beyond that, please post the code with which you've attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: you can use window.location.hash and window.onhashchange to check when the value changes.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (window.location.hash == "#hello") {
    document.getElementById("myElement").style.visibility = "visible"
} else {
    document.getElementById("myElement").style.visibility = "hidden"
}
```

You would probably want to get the element and set it to a variable instead of calling to the DOM both times, but you should get the idea here.  You could also use `display: none` instead of the visibility property if you wanted to.

Comment: Do you have a variable hello?

Comment: After the edit, it still will go into the else.  Hash will have a leading #

Answer (score 0):

for that you should use JavaScript and check if the URL has it or not and then select the element you want to add or remove a behavior..

```
var textElement = document.getElementById('myTextElement');
if(window.location.hash == '#hello'){
    textElement .style.display = 'block';
} else {
    textElement .style.display = 'none';
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with pure CSS through using the `:target` selector: When navigating to `yourpage.com/#id` an element is targeted, and as such the rules in the `:target` selector apply.

```css
#test{opacity:0;} 
#test:target{opacity:1}
```

```html
<div id="test">Can you see me?</div>
<a href="#test">click me</a>
```

Comment: The problem isn't to make something appear when clicking a button - but how to detect something specific in the URL. :)

Comment: This is great. Thanks. It's so obvious you can't see it.